# Populating mxml with JSON data containing urls

Tags: json, actionscript-3, apache-flex, datagrid, mxml

I just started learning Flex today. I faced a problem. I have some JSON data returned from my webservice, like this:

`[{"id":"34","url":"im3.png","uid":"1","pr":"1"},{"id":"33","url":"im2.jpg","uid":"1","pr":"0"},{"id":"32","url":"im1.jpg","uid":"1","pr":"1"}]`

I can decode it and store in array which populates my DataGrid.

`<mx:DataGrid id="prGallery" left="25" right="25" top="25" bottom="25" dataProvider="{prDB}">`

prDB is intialized "on load".

Everything works fine but... I would like to display images out of those URLs (images are stored on my server under `xxxxx.xx/url`.

Storing tags like `<img src="xxxxx.xx/url"/>` obviously doesn't work. So here come my questions:

1. Firstly, is it a good idea to use DataGrid for displaying images? (Even though I couldn't see the result I think it's not.)
2. What other component should I use in order to populate it with **unknown number** of records. (rows contain both text and image).

Answer (score 0):

1. Is it a good idea to use DataGrid? - It really depends on the size of the image and the outcome you see. If you are happy enough with the output, you can very well use it.
2. For unknown number of records, I would say DataGrid isn't a bad option. You can limit number of rows and implement pagination with a little use of server side code.

However, I didn't understand the part why can't you use `<img src="obj.url" />`. Are you not using itemRenderer for DataGrid columns? If not, consider it.

for e.g.,

`<mx:DataGrid id="myGrid" height="400" width="600" dataProvider="{jsonData}">

        <mx:columns>
            <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="id"/>
            <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="url" 
                itemRenderer="myComponents.ImageRenderer"/>
            <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="Price"/>
        </mx:columns>

  </mx:DataGrid>`

You will need to create a custom component `ImageRenderer` to display images.